# How can I authenticate with Wufoo to access their API from Java Script?

Tags: javascript, html, wufoo

I am trying to access the data from a form, so that I can use it in a custom application.

I need to be able to this in HTML, so I would like to use Java Script.

How would I send the API key(which is the username) and the password to Wufoo so that I can then access the JSON file that has the data I need?

It uses Basic HTTP authentication